# include a pseudoelement inside a anchor hover state

Tags: html, css

I have pseudoelements next to my links in a navigation menu. There are small downward arrows indicating a dropdown and On hover, the background changes. However, the only area that is covered is the active link and not the downward pointing arrow.

A sample of that is below:

```css
.item > a {
      color: #000;
      padding-top: 1.5rem;
      padding-bottom: 1.1rem;
}

.item > a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
}

.arrow-nav-item:after {
      content: '';
      border-left: 4px solid transparent;
      border-right: 4px solid transparent;
      border-top: 4px solid #5a5a5a;
      clear: both;
      position: absolute;
      top: 25px;
      right: 625px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
    <li class="item"><a class="arrow-nav-item" href="#">Main Item</a>
        <ul class="subitem">
          <li><a href="#">Chapter 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Basically I have an `::after` on my anchor tag which is positioned absolutely and is styled to look like a down arrow. On hover, a background appears, and I want the arrow included inside the colored hover area.

The reason it's not included I think is because of the absolute positioning - because when the arrow is relative, I can include it in the hover area. I don't think I can do that because giving the `:after` a relative positioning loses control of placement.

A couple of things I tried: add more right padding to the anchor, setting a fixed width on anchor and changing placement of pseudo-element (moving it to `<li>` tag) etc.

Should this be refactored to change? Is absolute positioning not the best way to handle these pseudoelements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `right` in that way will cause problems as the screen resizes. Instead, you can remove `absolute` positioning and position the anchor with `margin` instead...

```css
.item>a {
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.1rem;
}

.item>a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow-nav-item:after {
  content: '';
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #5a5a5a;
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.arrow-nav-item:hover:after {
  border-top-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li class="item"><a class="arrow-nav-item" href="#">Main Item</a>
    <ul class="subitem">
      <li><a href="#">Chapter 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this way makes more sense!

Answer (score 1):

While absolute-positioning would be a good way to handle this, you certainly don't want to be using giant offsets relative to the **[`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right)**. What I would recommend is to make use of **[`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)**, and simply set a small negative **[`margin-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left)** on the dropdown:

```css
.item>a {
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.1rem;
}

.item>a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow-nav-item:before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #5a5a5a;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li class="item"><a class="arrow-nav-item" href="#">Main Item</a>
    <ul class="subitem">
      <li><a href="#">Chapter 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that this makes the dropdown relative to the element's left-hand side, so it will always appear in the same place, regardless of the content of the `<li>. However, it still has the dropdown arrow outside of the``. The problem is that in order to have the background cover both components, you need to move the arrow inside the bullet points.

This can then be offset with **[`padding-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/padding-left)** on the `<a>` tag itself, so that the dropdown remains within the blue background:

```css
.item>a {
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.1rem;
}

.item>a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow-nav-item:before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #5a5a5a;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.arrow-nav-item {
  padding-left: 20px; /* Larger than margin-left */
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li class="item"><a class="arrow-nav-item" href="#">Main Item</a>
    <ul class="subitem">
      <li><a href="#">Chapter 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't think it's possible to have the dropdown arrow outside the bullet point and still retain the background, but hopefully this will suffice :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to keep `:after` and place it with margin, as that made the most sense for what I need to do